# How to use a Eaton 3S 700VA UPS with Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, ups

I have an Eaton 3S 700VA UPS connected to my modem, QNAP TS-412 and an Ubuntu Server.  The Eaton's USB connection goes into my Ubuntu Server.

I was wondering what software is the best for managing power interruptions.  Specifically, I want to get the Ubuntu Server to tell the QNAP to shut down when there is no power, send an email to my gmail, and shutdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual package used to monitor a UPS is [Network UPS Tools](http://www.networkupstools.org/), which is packaged in Ubuntu as `nut`.  Your model is [listed as supported](http://www.networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html?manufacturer=Eaton&model=3S) through the `usbhid-ups` driver on their website.

Among other features, NUT includes a client/server architecture that lets one machine [make the UPS status available over the network](http://www.networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.chunked/ar01s06.html#DataRoom).  This is useful in cases where you have a single UPS powering multiple machines, as in your situation.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the commands I used to setup `nut` for my Eaton 3s 700VA UPS on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo apt-get install nut

sudo vim /etc/nut/ups.conf
    [Eaton3S]
    driver=usbhid-ups
    port=auto

sudo vim /etc/nut/upsd.users
    [upsmon]
    password = pass
    upsmon master

sudo vim /etc/nut/upsmon.conf
    MONITOR Eaton3S@localhost 1 upsmon pass master

sudo vim /etc/nut/nut.conf
    MODE=standalone

sudo service nut start

sudo upsc Eaton3S
```

To have the modem shutdown and and have an email sent to yourself you'll need to write a bash script and edit `SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"` in /etc/nut/upsmon.conf